# Why there $hl(\overline{I})=d(\overline{I})$?

Tags: general-topology

See the example 1.20. (Sorry the picture is not clear. You can see [the link](http://picpaste.com/2-2ln5Aglj.png) where it is more clear. )

[image]

> Why there $hl(\overline{I})=d(\overline{I})$?

Thanks ahead:)

Comment: There's quite a bit of notation, terminology, and abbreviation, here....

Comment: @Cameron: All pretty standard for anyone working with cardinal functions, though. And Paul’s been asking questions about this cluster of topics for a while now. You’ll find the paper [here](http://www.few.vu.nl/~vanmill/papers/papers2011/al-ju-vm-tk-wi.pdf).

Comment: @Brian: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I$ is a dense subset of $\overline I$, so if $I$ is countable, then certainly $d(\overline I)=\omega$.

$L_j$ is a LOTS, so $\overline I$ is a GO-space. Bennett, Lutzer, & Matveev, *The monotone Lindelöf property and separability in ordered spaces*, Topology and its Applications, Volume 151, issue 1-3 (June 1, 2005), p. 180-186, showed that every separable GO-space is hereditarily monotonically Lindelöf and hence hereditarily Lindelöf. If $I$ is countable, then $\overline I$ is separable, and hence $hl(\overline I)=\omega$.

(I’m sure that this can be proved more easily, but this was at hand.)

Comment: Thanks Brain. So do we have $hl(X)=d(X)=c(X)$ if $X$ is a GO-space?

Comment: @Paul: It’s not even necessarily true that $d(X)=c(X)$ for a LOTS: a Suslin line is a counterexample, and it’s consistent with ZFC that Suslin lines exist. It is true that $hl(X)=s(X)=c(X)$ for a GO-space $X$.